# Choosing bluetooth speaker with auto connect

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I would like to use a stand-alone bluetooth speaker as a replacement for my existing car stereo since the sound quality is quite poor and it doesn't have bluetooth.

I would however like the experience to be as smooth as possible when I start the car. I don't want to push any buttons.

What I'm looking for is a bluetooth speaker that can sit in my car charging from the 12v outlet, and as soon it start the car it will automatically connect.

This seems like a simple feature to me. However I have no idea to look for in the spec sheet when buying a bluetooth speaker. Does this feature have a name?

Comment: I had to modify your question slightly. Product endorsement is considered a shopping question, which would make this question off-topic for the site.

Comment: This seems to be about generic bluetooth speakers, not motor vehicles. how those speakers work is not on topic here.